# Highcharts How to add data label to last data point of a series

Tags: highcharts

I built a line chart: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/vyar6h0q/2/)

Now I want to add a data label to the last data point of each series.

I tried with formatter:

```
if (this.x == visiblePoints[visiblePoints.length - 1].x)
```

but some series do not have a data point for the last date. How can I get the length of existing data?

Answer (score 2):

As you rightly notice you need to use the `formatter` function for data labels. Use below code to check if the point is the last one.

```
series: {
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    formatter: function() {
      var seriesPoints = this.series.points;
      if (this.point === seriesPoints[seriesPoints.length - 1]) {
        return 'Last label point';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uqrt2j9d/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.dataLabels

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, both series get the data from the same csv file. But some series have blanks for the last datetime x value. In these cases I want the data label to be displayed at the last non blank value.

Comment: Hi @Johannes Christ, You have points with `null` y valie in the `visiblePoints` array. In the filter function you need to check: `typeof p.x === 'number' && typeof p.y === 'number'`